# Connecting a button to a method is swift doesn't work

Tags: button, methods, swift

I am trying to drag a button with ctrl to a method in swift xcode. but somehow I cannot connect the button to a method in the code. No line appears in the code.
Can someone help me?

I am dragging a button line to ViewController. I am supposted to get a line to add an IBAction function, but i am getting no such line. POB. I am using swift, not Objective C

Comment: Perhaps this video [What is an IBOutlet?](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-a-simple-iphone-app/getting-started-with-iphone/what-is-an-iboutlet-2) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drag the button to the class of the ViewController (the header area where you declare class variables), not into a method of the ViewController. This will result in the IBAction line that you are looking for.